Adding Privacy Manifest to CocoaPods iOS SDK
I have a SDK distributed as XCFramework via cocoapods. I have added the PrivacyInfo file in the Resource folder and specify in the podspec as below.
s.resource_bundles = {"MyFramework_Privacy" => ["Resources/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy"]}

Also verified that PrivacyInfo file has been copied in to different arch folders in XCframework

However when the consumer app use our SDK and were notified by Apple that they need to provide usage reasons for the required reason APIs and I am not sure why the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file that we have shipped not been considered. Any idea please?
Filetree structure

PrivacyInfo file


Not sure why this question got a down vote. I am still facing the issues when include PrivacyInfo file with XCFramewok. Similar issue also mentioned in apple developer forum as well https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/745546

Are you sure the path to the xcprivacy file is correct and it have all the required keys in it?

Could you please provide the whole file tree structure and the content of the manifest file

I have updated the question with file tree structure and the contents of the privacy file. I think the path defined in the podspec file is correct, because I can see the privacy file copied in to the  different arch folders in XCframework

Are they linking your framework statically or dynamically? If they do dynamically then things should work. If they're doing it statically, then Xcode should have merged the xcprivacies, but Xcode currently isn't doing that. Yet Apple gives throws an error at you...

See here for more on static linking. tldr if they're doing static linking, then see if your client can link dynamically instead...

@mfaani thanks for the info. App is linking our framework statically. One more thing we observed recently, It seems like all declarations from SDKs are not considered in case a Required reason API symbol is found in the app. Or maybe that the sdks are not yet scanned. Could be an issue in the Apple side according to discussion thread you have mentioned above.

So far, Apple's warning emails have only included the app itself and the app extensions.
Apple also recently added page that has instructions for including manifests with static libraries. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/adding_a_privacy_manifest_to_your_app_or_third-party_sdk
From your screenshot, the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy is missing 2 of the 4 required entries.  That may be why there are issues with Apple detecting and using it.
The four entries from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files
NSPrivacyTracking
NSPrivacyTrackingDomains
NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes
NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes


Thanks for the update. I have submitted the sample app with integrated our sdk with exact same setup as mentioned in my original question. This time app went thru the beta review successfully :) It seems Apple have fixed the issue.

Check Bundle Identifier
Verify File Location
Confirm File Contents
Test Locally
Surely one of those options will work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
